# Simplifying Complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Help me simplify this complex number:

Hints are welcome, so that I can see how to move on

$$\left(\frac{1+6i}{\sqrt{76}e^{\frac{1}{2}\pi i}}\right)^{2i}$$

Comment: Have you tried transforming the numerator in exponential form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left(\frac{1+6i}{\sqrt{76}e^{\frac{1}{2}\pi i}}\right)^{2i}=$$

$$\left(3-\frac{i}{2}\right)^{2i}\frac{1}{19^i}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$e^{\pi i/2}=i$$

After that you should apply the complex power definition.

$$z^w=e^{w\log z}$$